# I'm trying to define PI at 3.14159 without importing anything. How do I do it?

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a script that asks for the radius of a circle and solves it for the area. I've tried googling it but I've all I've gotten are answers with import somewhere in the script or some really complex stuff that I don't understand and I'm not going to copy paste because I wouldn't learn anything from that.

```
print("What is the radius?")
radius=input()
def PI 3.14159
area=PI*radius**2
print("The area of the circle is",area)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What's wrong with defining a variable like `pi = 3.14159`?

Answer (score 4):

Variable assignments in python are done like so:

```
PI = 3.14158
```

You don't need do declare the variable or its type.

You can't declare a constant in python, so we rely on using capitals to denote "*do not change this value*". This is laid out in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants), the "*Style Guide for Python Code*":

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include `MAX_OVERFLOW` and `TOTAL`.

---

`def` is used to introduce a function, for example:

```
def pi():
    return 3.14158
```

You could then use the returned value like this:

```
area = pi() * radius**2
```

Comment: Yeah, but they do it correct ***on the next line***...

Comment: i'd use PI instead of pi. I think its common to capitalize constants

Comment: Yep, strange huh. It's worth giving people who are new to writing code a helping hand though, and expanding on what `def` might do...

Comment: @GrantWilliams done

Comment: What other feedback where you looking for on the downvote?  Thought mine was tacit enough there...

Comment: Huh. I don't think that attitude is helpful or welcoming for beginners - many languages have a keyword for constants, so I thought the question was fair enough... though admittedly a duplicate, I tried to add more useful info to my answer.